# The pipe 'searchfilter' could not be found?

Tags: angular

I have custom Pipe. That I imported to ngModule of component.

```
declarations: [SearchFilterPipe]
```

In this component I try to use this pipe as:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of studyPlan | searchfilter : value">
```

It gives me an error: `The pipe 'searchfilter' could not be found`. 
Also variable `value` is not available in this line.

Pipe is:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchfilter'
})

@Injectable()
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) { return []; }
    return items.filter(it => it[field] === value);
  }
}
```

Module of component is:

```
@NgModule({
     ...
     declarations: [SearchFilterPipe],
      exports: [SearchFilterPipe]

})
```

Comment: share code of the pipe

Comment: Done, see again

Comment: see the answer from @GünterZöchbauer , see point 2 and 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either

- the `@Pipe({name: 'searchfilter'})` decorator doesn't exactly match
- `declarations: [SearchFilterPipe]` is not in the same module as the component containing `<div *ngFor="let item of studyPlan | searchfilter : value">`
- `imports: [TheModuleContainingThePipe]` is missing if the pipe and the component that uses it are part of different modules.
- `exports: [SearchFilterPipe]` is missing in the `@NgModule()` that contains the pipe.

Comment: Where is this: `imports: [TheModuleContainingThePipe]`?

Comment: If you add a pipe to `declarations: []`, this only makes the pipe available for components in the same module. If the pipe is in a different module, the module needs to have the pipe in declarations and export the pipe, and the module the component that uses it needs to have the module with the pipe in `imports: []`

Comment: `Where is this: imports: [TheModuleContainingThePipe]` The `@NgModule({...})` the component is part of.

Comment: How many modules (`@NgModule()`) do you have in your code? Are the pipe and the component that uses the pipe part of the same module?

Comment: Maybe problem is in that I use nested component. child is inside main. So I need pipe in child

Comment: Yes the component uses the module where I imported pipe

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of your last comment. Do you have exactly one module for your whole application, or do you have more than one modules?

Comment: I have some modules in application

Comment: And are the pipe and the component that uses the pipe part of the same module?

Comment: What was missing in the end?

Comment: I will post answer later :)